# Best way to hash multiple keys in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a set of four numbers and they together make up a key. So, a unique combination of them should correspond lead to one value. What is the best way to prepare a hashmap for this purpose. The options are -

1) Make a unique key through concatenating them into a string
2) Make a unique key through adding them up (multiplying some of them with powers of 10 to avoid duplication).
3) Make a class that has the four numbers as fields and hash an instance of the class.

And if it is the third, I can't figure out how to implement this approach (assuming it is possible). The code below should print 2, but prints nothing.

```
 AdjFactor a = new AdjFactor(2,3,4,5);
    AdjFactor b = new AdjFactor(3,3,4,5);
    HashMap<AdjFactor,Double> factrs = new HashMap<>();
    factrs.put(a, 1d);
    factrs.put(b, 2d);
    AdjFactor c = new AdjFactor(1,3,4,5);
    AdjFactor d = new AdjFactor(3,3,4,5);
    if(factrs.containsKey(c)){
        System.out.println(factrs.get(c));
    }
    if(factrs.containsKey(d)){
        System.out.println(factrs.get(d));
    }
```

Here is my AdjFactor class -

```
public class AdjFactor {
public int demo;
public int month;
public int year;
public int site;

AdjFactor(int demo1,int month1,int year1,int site1){
    this.demo = demo1;
    this.month = month1;
    this.year = year1;
    this.site = site1;
 }
public boolean equals(AdjFactor a, AdjFactor b){
    if(a.demo==b.demo && a.month==b.month && a.year==b.year && a.site==b.site)return true;
    else return false;
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the structure of your AdjFactor class ?

Comment: What do you mean by `best way`?

Comment: memory is top priority and next is speed.

Comment: Go with 3; and don't forget to implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`!

Comment: For 3, I need a .contains() equivalent. The above (default) isn't working.

Comment: This is normal, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code below should print 2, but prints nothing.

This is because your `AdjFactor` class does not implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`...

As a result, it uses `Object`'s defaults; and an `Object` `.equals()` another one if and only if they are exactly the same references!

==> implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` for your class

[Obligatory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), [links](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for you to read. If you use Java 7, look at the `Objects` class which can help you.

**EDIT** sample implementation:

```
public class AdjFactor 
{
    // ....
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return demo ^ month ^ year ^ site;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final AdjFactor other = (AdjFactor) obj;
        return demo == other.demo
            && month == other.month
            && year == other.year
            && site == other.site;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to implement them? I tried implementing equals -

Comment: Uh, there are a s*load of links which would have told you that... Edited anyway.

Comment: Use `java.util.Objects.hash` for a better hash function.

Answer (score 1):

And regarding the hashcode question, you will be ok with

```
Arrays.hashCode(new int[] { demo, month, year, site });
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need this spelled out. What will the code look like?

Comment: Just return this in your `hashCode()` method